# How to iterate through nested children of an object and collect an array of names

Tags: javascript, oop, currying

There is n number of parent and child in an object

```
var obj={
    name:'one',
    child:{
        name:'two',
        child:{
            name:'three',
            child..
        }
    }
} 

foo(obj)
```

Write a function to get output as `['one', 'two, 'three', ...]`

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Write a recursive function.

Comment: _"Write a function to get output as `['one', 'two, 'three', ...]`"_ What have you written? No effort to solve own question appears at OP. In fact, no actual question appears at text of OP.

Comment: `foo = o => o ? [o.name, ...foo(o.child)] : []` <-- hand this in and either fail when asked to explain OR understand it, become an aspiring developer and find success and happiness in life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following recursive function `getAllNames()`:

```js
/**
 * Collects all `name` property values recursively
 *
 * @param o    an object
 * @param res  the resulting array
 * @returns {*|Array}
 */
function getAllNames(o, res) {
    var names = res || [];
    for (var k in o) {
        if (k === 'name') {
            names.push(o[k]);   // saving `name` value
        } else if(k === 'child' && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            getAllNames(o[k], names);  // processing nested `child` object
        }
    }
    return names;
}

var obj = {
    name:'one',
    child:{
        name:'two',
        child:{
            name:'three',
            child: {
                name: 'four',
                child: {
                    name: 'five'
                }  
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log(getAllNames(obj, []));
```

Comment: Wouldn't directly accessing the properties be more efficient & readable than iterating over all of them? Just trying to understand your intention as your code shows experience.

Comment: @le_m, welcome. I'm trying to write unified solutions. Consider, that the input object can be like `var obj = {
        name:'one',
        child:{
            title: 'text',
            child:{
                name:'three',
                child: {
                    name: 'four'
                }  }   }  };` (some nested objects have no `name` key or have another keys). My solution will collect values for only needed key(`name`)

Answer (score 1):

you should use a recursive function

```
var result = [];

function searchChildren(parent){
    if(parent.child){
        result.push(parent.name);
        searchChildren(parent.child);
    }
}

searchChildren(obj);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zrbfm9ud/

Comment: The output not correct, last child not appear but it's very good job (Y) @stackoverfloweth

Comment: nice one! I made a simplification on it (with credit to you of course ). see my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it, basically you return and have function call itself again. Kinda like a loop.

```
var obj={
    name:'one',
    child:{
        name:'two',
        child:{
            name:'three'
        }
    }
} 


function foo(obj, arr) {
  if (!obj) return arr;
  arr.push(obj.name);
  return foo(obj.child, arr);
}

var results = foo(obj,[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop to iterate through each level of your object until `object.child` cannot be found:

```js
function foo(object) {
  var result = []
  while (object) {
    result.push(object.name)
    object = object.child
  }
  return result
}

var object = {
  name: 'one',
  child: {
    name: 'two',
    child: {
      name: 'three'
    }
  }
}

console.log(foo(object)) //=> ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generator and curry the object and the numbers, you want.

```js
function setObject(object) {
    return function* (n) {
        while (n--) {
            yield object.name;
            object = object.child;
        }
    }
}

var obj = { name: 'one', child: { name: 'two', child: { name: 'three', child: { name: 'four', child: { name: 'five' } } } } },
    getNumbers = setObject(obj);

console.log([...getNumbers(4)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: if we have a  curried function like this                           
          function add(a){                                                                                     
      //can we find out anything about the second curried argument () in add(1) -->(2)<-- in this scope?                                                                                         
                       return function(b){                                                             return a+b}}                                                    add(1)(2)

Comment: You are the best, Thank you!   : - )

Comment: @Arrow, what would you like to get? which information?

Comment: You know something, I just realized that curried functions are evaluated from right to left. I was thinking of a thunk or a nullary function. My bad #_#

Comment: i reall don't get you. please add a bit more, what you want.

Answer (score 1):

@stackoverfloweth's answer seemed the best to me as it is really simple and efficient. But I think it can be even simpler, and also I made it include the last level:

```js
var obj={
    name:'one',
    child:{
        name:'two',
        child:{
            name:'three'
        }
    }
} 

var res = [];
function search(obj){
    res.push(obj.name);
    !obj.child || search(obj.child);
}

search(obj);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
funtion f1(array, obj){
  if(obj){
   if(obj.name){
     array.push(obj.name);
   }
   if(obj.child){
     return f1(array, obj.child);
   }
 }
 return array;
}


funtion f2(array, obj){
  while(obj){
    if(obj.name){
      array.push(obj.name);
    }
    obj = obj.child;

   }

   return array;
}

function foo(obj){
 var array = [];
 //recursive version
 return f1(array, obj); 
 // non recursive version
 //return f2(array, obj);
}

foo(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many answers check for the undefined child as the argument of the function to terminate the recursion. This means an extra call which can be avoided

```
function doit (obj, arr = []){
    arr.push(obj.name);
    return obj.child ? doit(obj.child, arr) : arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will output array like this
`["one", "two", "three"]`

```js
var obj = {
  name: 'one',
  child: {
    name: 'two',
    child: {
      name: 'three'
    }
  }
}

var str = parser(obj);
var arr = str.substring(0, str.length - 1).split(";");

console.log(arr); // Output ["one", "two", "three"]

function parser(obj) {
  var text = obj.name + ";";
  if (obj.child) text += parser(obj.child);
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var string = foo(obj);
var array = str.substring(0, str.length - 1).split(",");

console.log(array);

function foo(obj) {
  var total= obj.name + ",";
  if (obj.child !=null) total= total+ foo(obj.child);
  return total;
}
```